# String input with or without ""?

Tags: discussion, policy

When challenges require to read a string via STDIN/Console I have seen people interpreting that in mainly two ways. The first one was that you actually just have to type the string as

```
This is an example string.
```

the second way required you to also type some sort of delimiter (usually double `"` or single `'` quotes)

```
"This is an example string."
```

or

```
'This is an example string.'
```

The question now is: Which one of those does actually count as *string input via STDIN*?

I am not sure, but I can imagine that there are languages where only one of those methods is possible for accepting strings as input.

On the other hand it might be easier (in codegolf: shorter) in some languages to use one or the other way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Unless the challenge specifies, either is acceptable

Just be sure to mention what form of input your program requires in your explanation.

Comment: I don't think it _really_ matters; all it really comes down to is how your language accepts input. If they disallow certain types of input, then yeah, of course you can't use it, but otherwise, why not?

Comment: Is it correct that you mean as long as the OP does not explicitly say that the input cannot be assumed to be delimited, you *can* assume the string to be or not to be delimited if you want to submit a program that requires it to be either way?

Comment: @flawr this is exactly what I mean

Answer (score 8):

### Without quotes

I have always assumed that quotes weren't allowed.

In the ideal case, I think standard input should be the same for everyone and contain the challenge input as plainly as possible. This is how online judges work (e.g. codegolf.com), although I realise PPCG is a bit different.

Allowing stdin to be pre-formatted with quotes seems unnecessary, and will inevitably be abused. I'm not aware of any languages that read from stdin but strictly require quotes.

It's also worth pointing out that up to 541 [existing Python 2 answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=raw_input+%5Bcode-golf%5D+is%3Aanswer) could be shortened by using `input()` with quotes around each line in place of `raw_input()`.

Comment: Abusing quotes in Haskell:  you can use `readLn` instead of `getLine` if the input is surrounded with `"`.

Comment: Also, Mathematica could use `Input[]` instead of `InputString[]`.

Comment: I prefer this method because it avoids potential problems with the `"` characters needing to be in the input. I also think it can help with people trying to coerce the challenge into just being an `eval(input())` sort of deal.

Comment: Python 2: `input()` accepts `"double-quoted strings"` and `'single-quoted strings'` as input, as opposed to `raw_input()`, which accepts `non-quoted strings` for +4 bytes. That's an example of why your answer is not good.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ what?